# boto3: aws workspace: create_workspace: Throwing error

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-workspaces

Hi I am trying to create a workspace using boto3

```
def awsWorkspaceCreation(event, context):
    client = boto3.client('workspaces')
    response = client.create_workspaces(
        Workspaces=[
            {
                'DirectoryId': 'd-9067b1946c',
                'UserName': 'hhsjhdhtest',
                'BundleId': 'wsb-cys0c7ctl',
                'WorkspaceProperties': {
                    'RunningMode': 'AUTO_STOP'
                }
            },
        ]
    )
    return {"status":"success"}
```

I am getting the below error. Now sure whats the problem

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Could not connect to the endpoint URL: \"https://workspaces.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/\"",
  "errorType": "EndpointConnectionError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/handler.py\", line 73, in awsWorkspaceCreation\n    'Value': 'CallCentreProvisioned'\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/botocore/client.py\", line 316, in _api_call\n    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/botocore/client.py\", line 622, in _make_api_call\n    operation_model, request_dict, request_context)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/botocore/client.py\", line 641, in _make_request\n    return self._endpoint.make_request(operation_model, request_dict)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/botocore/endpoint.py\", line 102, in make_request\n    return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/botocore/endpoint.py\", line 137, in _send_request\n    success_response, exception):\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/botocore/endpoint.py\", line 256, in _needs_retry\n    caught_exception=caught_exception, request_dict=request_dict)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/botocore/hooks.py\", line 356, in emit\n    return self._emitter.emit(aliased_event_name, **kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/botocore/hooks.py\", line 228, in emit\n    return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/botocore/hooks.py\", line 211, in _emit\n    response = handler(**kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/botocore/retryhandler.py\", line 183, in __call__\n    if self._checker(attempts, response, caught_exception):\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/botocore/retryhandler.py\", line 251, in __call__\n    caught_exception)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/botocore/retryhandler.py\", line 277, in _should_retry\n    return self._checker(attempt_number, response, caught_exception)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/botocore/retryhandler.py\", line 317, in __call__\n    caught_exception)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/botocore/retryhandler.py\", line 223, in __call__\n    attempt_number, caught_exception)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/botocore/retryhandler.py\", line 359, in _check_caught_exception\n    raise caught_exception\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/botocore/endpoint.py\", line 200, in _do_get_response\n    http_response = self._send(request)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/botocore/endpoint.py\", line 269, in _send\n    return self.http_session.send(request)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/botocore/httpsession.py\", line 283, in send\n    raise EndpointConnectionError(endpoint_url=request.url, error=e)\n"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Where's this code running?

Answer (score 0):

As the exception indicates, your code is unable to establish a connection to the Workspace's API Endpoint.
This is primarily due to your Elastic Network Interface being situated within a private subnet.
While you haven't specified where your code is running (e.g., on an EC2 instance or within a Lambda function with VPC Access), the core issue and its solutions remain consistent across all environments.

There are **three potential solutions** to address this:

- Relocate your code to a resource [within a public subnet](https://www.learnaws.org/2022/06/22/public-private-subnets/).
- Introduce a [NAT Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html) in a public subnet of the same VPC, routing the outbound connections of the private subnet through it.
- Implement a [VPC Interface Endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/create-interface-endpoint.html) for AWS Workspace.